# Ansible validate required extra-var

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an Ansible playbook where I import other Ansible playbooks and I take some extra-vars from command line. I want them to be required.

```
- import_playbook: nginx.yml
    test_first="test first"
- import_playbook: nginx1.yml
    test_two={"hello":"{{test}}"}
```

I am taking the `test` as an extra-var from command line. I want it to be required.

I tried the following code, but it gives error:

```
- import_playbook: nginx.yml
    test_first="test first"
  tasks:
    - fail: msg="Error"
      when: not (test is defined)
- import_playbook: nginx1.yml
    test_two={"hello":"{{test}}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tasks` should be a key in a play, so you must define a play, for example:

```
- import_playbook: nginx.yml
    test_first="test first"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - fail: msg="Error"
      when: not (test is defined)

- import_playbook: nginx1.yml
    test_two={"hello":"{{test}}"}
```